# Record audio in stereo iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, core-audio

I'm developing an app to record audio  and do some signal processing. I was wondering how to get a PCM audio buffer in stereo.

Is possible to record in stereo if I connect a dual microphone in the 3.5 mm jack of the iPhone?

Is posible to use the dual microphone of the iPhone to record in Stereo?

Can I record in stereo using a usb dual microphone? or using a usb sound card with two or more channels for audio input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A USB microphone in conjunction with the Apple Lightning to USB Camera Adapter or USB Camera Connection kit will allow recording stereo input to the RemoteIO Audio Unit.

The 3.5 mm headset plug only has a mono microphone connection.